Using IBM Guardium to scan my databases for user/roles details using out the box reports, where can I see the SELECT statements being run?
We would like to provide our DBA team with the SELECT statements that the out of box reports from Guardium use when scanning our databases to validate the accuracy and completeness.  Recently I have noticed that Guardium is not picking up on a set of users that our DBA is saying is present for a DB2 server that we are scanning.  I would like to provide the DBA with the SELECT statements that were ran by the Guardium report to produce the entitlement details.  The DBA can then analyze the SELECT statements for accuracy.
I did try running the debugger while the report was running.  When the report was finished running i viewed the debug file, but i am not sure if these are the correct SQL SELECT statements.
